# Change request format based on subdomain in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

On my Rails 3 site, if a user comes in through a certain subdomain (say, `mob.example.com`), I want to change the request format of that request to be ":mobile".

What's the most sensible way to do this, and where should I put this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up doing this in the way I thought was most reasonable:

```
module MobilizedController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :set_mobile_request_format, :if => :mobile_subdomain?
  end 

  private

  def set_mobile_request_format
    request.format = :mobile
  end 

  def mobile_subdomain?
    request.subdomains.include? 'm' 
  end 
end

class ApplicationController
  include MobilizedController
end
```